# WooCommerce API doesn't create product with SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have this code that creates a new product in WooCommerce:

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://www.xxxx.com.br', 
    'ck_xxxxxx', 
    'cs_xxxxxx',
    [
        'wp_api' => true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
        'version' => 'wc/v1' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
    ]
);

    $data = [
        'name' => 'Premium Quality',
        'type' => 'variable', 
        'sku' => '123450000',
    ];

    print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
```

The product is inserted into the database with the name **Premium Quality**, the problem is that the **SKU is not inserted**, and when I try to view in the WordPress panel I see that it is empty.

Why is this happening?

My wordpress and WooCommerce are upgraded to the latest version (and my PHP API too => 1.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try with curl

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"name\": \"Premium Quality\",\n  \"type\": \"variable\",\n  \"sku\" : \"123450000\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: Basic ",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```